# Listen for notifications from a specific app / identify another app's object handle

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm writing an application that needs to listen for notifications published by a specific application (which is not mine) in the background. I was wondering how I could efficiently do this. Based on this (basic) information from apple (http://www.idev101.com/code/Cocoa/Notifications.html), it looks like if I can identify the app's object handle, I could accomplish this, but I'm not certain how I should go about that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for `NSNotificationCenter`:

> An NSNotificationCenter object can deliver notifications only within a single program.

So, no, you cannot listen for notifications from another app.